# Installing homebrew and getting the PATH correct (permanently)

Tags: python, homebrew

I have installed Homebrew on my MacOS and I have been going through some online tutorials, but it's not quite working.

A frequent error message I get is `-bash: brew: command not found`.

I suspect this is because my PATH is not correct. I have tried `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and it seems to work temporarily, but after a while, it seems to go wrong. How do I set my PATH so that it is correct, and stays fixed?

Comment: To set the path permanently, have you tried to edit your ~/.bashrc file to contain the line export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH".? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/148919

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you type this on the terminal?

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

The re-installation should fix the PATH.

```
which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

Comment: Yes, that installs homebrew for me, doesn't it?

Comment: yes and sets automatically the PATH. Then `brew` command should work fine

Comment: Thanks. It works for now. It's all quite confusing!

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking - do you know where my python actually is? If I'm honest, I don't know where /usr/local/bin actually is

Comment: @pythonnewbie If you want to get a better handle on the macOS folder hierarchy, I'd recommend exploring it in the Finder: First, go to the root directory (choose Go menu > Go to Folder, enter "`/`" as the path to go to, and press Go). Then make it show normally-invisible items by pressing Command-Shift-Period. There are a *lot* of invisible things in the root directory, but only a few are relevant. Then switch to Column view (choose View menu > as Columns), and go exploring. Select `usr`, then `local` under that, then `bin` under that.

Comment: Some relevant links: an [OS X Daily article on getting at the root folder](http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/17/access-root-directory-mac-os-x/), and an [apple.SE answer with a map of some of the normally-hidden parts of the filesystem hierarchy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119230/what-is-standard-for-os-x-filesystem-e-g-opt-vs-usr/119265#119265).